# How can I use the application twice as dependency

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

The Elixir/Erlang `application` might have dependent applications. As by documentation:

> you can configure the generated
>   application by defining an application/0 function in your `mix.exs` with the
>   following options:
>
> ```
> • :applications - all applications your application depends on at
>   runtime. By default, this list is automatically inferred from your
>   dependencies. Any extra Erlang/Elixir dependency must be specified in
>   :extra_applications. Mix and other tools use the application list in order
>   to start your dependencies before starting the application itself.
> • :extra_applications - a list of Erlang/Elixir applications that you
>   want started before your application. For example, Elixir's :logger or
>   Erlang's :crypto.
> ```

These dependent applications will be all started before starting my application. So far so good.

The `applications` key expects a list of atoms, it does not allow tuples. That makes it impossible to pass parameters to [`Application.start/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#c:start/2).

**Is there any robust way to pass the `start_args` to the dependent application**, or am I forced to tweak the default behaviour with manual `MyApp.start(:normal, [:hello])`?

If the answer is “yes,” how can I also start the same dependent application *twice* with different list of `start_args`?

Comment: I'm not sure about passing arguments, but I'm sure you can't start a single application multiple times.

Comment: Is there any reason for that? If I have, say, 2 different redis sources, it would be way cleaner to have 2 apps handling those. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need multiple instances of an app to support multiple Redis  connections. Just use the supervision tree of your own app to call `Redix.start_link()` multiple times with different params.

Comment: @MikeBuhot `redis` was a contrived example. I know how to start two different workers, but the application approach like (pseudo) `{:archiver, [dest: ...]}, {:archiver, [dest: ...]}` looks way cleaner to me.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but FWIW: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-April/078836.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. Elixir does not all the same application to be started multiple times. However, there may be some tricks you could do.

By adding `app: false` to the deps, the app will not be started automatically.

```
{:my_dep, "...", app: false}
```

Then you could start it form your main application.

```
MyDep.Application.start(...)
```

You may then be able to start additional workers in the app early in your main supervisor.

Some things you need to be aware of in the app.

- Does the application use named processes? That will be a problem.
- Does the application have global configuration? That could be a problem.

But all of this really depends on the dependency you are trying to use.

Comment: `app: false` is a key, thank you. I understand induced problems with named processes (the application is mine and I name processes with “global application `name` in mind, that’s why I asked about “how to pass parameters in the first place,) global configuration is not a problem as well, since I always can manage configuration before starting apps.

Comment: I was wondering if it was your own app. That makes it simple :)

Comment: Honestly, I do not see any reason to not allow that via `{:myapp, [[name: "Blah", ...]]}` in `applications` callback (assuming the application is ready to be started multiple times.) After all, the application can start multiple supervisors and they in turn might start multiple workers, and the same naming issue comes up. I believe it could have been rooted at OTP core structure.